# How do I convert the code of creating a file to updating a file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-drive-api, google-api-nodejs-client

Is there a way to convert a create file code to an update file code.  I'm new to coding Javascript and I need an example of this.  I really want to find a way to update my old google drive files and make them much better.

```
const { google } = require('googleapis');
const path = require('path')
const fs = require('fs')

const CLIENT_ID = '898005425789-ie9c7s59ri74mmg6hp2iouamo3vrd09d.apps.googleusercontent.com';
const CLIENT_SECRET = 'qXCxqGgRH8woQG5wlK0WK79k';
const REDIRECT_URI = 'https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground';

const REFRESH_TOKEN = 
'1//04SmYavGXSUwQCgYIARAAGAQSNwF-L9IrhcLntTl1298HgjIUvrmRauA81x-ZI9ddwg9h1C7Q0fzhqR2f1dvawTO3A00LoWy-V5g'

const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
  CLIENT_ID,
  CLIENT_SECRET,
  REDIRECT_URI
);

oauth2Client.setCredentials({ refresh_token: REFRESH_TOKEN });

const drive = google.drive({
  version: 'v3',
  auth: oauth2Client,
});

const filePath = path.join(__dirname, 'sus.jpg');

async function uploadFile() {
  try {
    const response = await drive.files.create({
      requestBody: {
        name: 'suseyes.jpg',
        mimeType: 'image/jpg',
        createdTime: "2017-03-13T05:51:43.030Z",
        modifiedTime: "2018-07-21T05:51:43.030Z",
        description: "hi",
        filePath: '/upload/drive/v3/files/test/',
      },
      media: {
        mimeType: 'image/jpg',
        body: fs.createReadStream(filePath),
      },
    });

    console.log(response.data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
}

uploadFile();
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe your goal and your current situation as follows.

- You want to update the existing file using googleapis for Node.js.

  - The file is an image file (JPEG file).
  - From your script, I thought that you are using Node.js.
- You have already been able to get and put values for the file on Google Drive using Drive API.

#### Modification points:

- When the file is updated, `createdTime` cannot be updated. It seems that this is the current specification. When it tries to modify `createdTime`, an error like `The resource body includes fields which are not directly writable.` occurs.
- When you want to update the file, it is required to include `fileId` in the request.
- `filePath: '/upload/drive/v3/files/test/'` cannot be used in the request body.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
const response = await drive.files.create({
  requestBody: {
    name: 'suseyes.jpg',
    mimeType: 'image/jpg',
    createdTime: "2017-03-13T05:51:43.030Z",
    modifiedTime: "2018-07-21T05:51:43.030Z",
    description: "hi",
    filePath: '/upload/drive/v3/files/test/',
  },
  media: {
    mimeType: 'image/jpg',
    body: fs.createReadStream(filePath),
  },
});
```

To:

```
const fileId = "###"; // Please set the file ID of the file you want to update.
const filePath = "###"; // Please set the filename with the path.

const response = await drive.files.update(
  {
    fileId: fileId,
    requestBody: {
      name: "suseyes.jpg",
      mimeType: "image/jpg",
      // createdTime: "2017-03-13T05:51:43.030Z",  // This cannot be included.
      modifiedTime: "2018-07-21T05:51:43.030Z",
      description: "hi",
    },
    media: {
      mimeType: "image/jpg",
      body: fs.createReadStream(filePath),
    },
  });
```

#### Note:

- In this case, there might be the files you cannot update using the image file. So please be careful this.

#### Reference:

- [Files: update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update)